# Including categorical variables in Bayesian Model Averaging

Tags: r

I am running a bayesian model averaging for a problem in R. However, the package BMS in R does not allow inclusion of categorical and dummy variables. But my problem require the use of such variables. How do I include dummy variables in bayesian model averaging in R?

Comment: If you have have questions about statistical modeling, then you should ask over at [stats.se] instead.

Answer (score 0):

rstanarm package is built upon the same sintaxis as base r 'lm' and allows the introduction of categorical variables.